# Error 91excel vba

Tags: vba

he desarrollado una macro excel en el libro "A", la ejecuto llamándola desde otro libro el "B". En el libro "B" copio una hoja excel "datos" que se genera en un proceso de exportación a excel de un libro "C" que contiene la hoja "datos".
Si en el libro "B" creo una hoja nueva llamada "datos" y copio en esta hoja las celdas de la hoja datos del libro "C" la macro funciona bien. Sin embargo si copio la hoja "datos" del libro "C" al libro "B" y ejecuto la macro aparece el mensaje

> Se ha producido el error 91 en tiempo de ejecución: Variable de objeto
>   o bloque with no establecido

Y la macro se detiene en la instrucción

```
Worksheets("AVEVACons").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
```

Alguna sugerencia?
Gracias

Comment: ¿Cuál es el libro activo en el momento en que se ejecuta esta instrucción? Tal cual lo tienes escrito, esta instrucción se ejecuta en el libro activo en ese momento.

Comment: El libro activo es el libro "B" donde esta la hoja de datos  "AVEVACons".

Comment: La macro deja de funcionar si la hoja de datos "AVEVACons" la copio y pego desde el libro "C" al "B". Sin embargo si creo una hoja nueva en el libro "B" con el nombre "AVEVACons" y copio los datos desde la hoja "AVEVACons" del libro "C" y los pego en la hoja "AVECACons" vacía creada en el libro "B" la macro funciona bien. El efecto es como si no reconoce la hoja copiada del libro "C" al "B".

Comment: ¿Has probado a hacer antes que el Libro C sea el activo?

Comment: No, porque el libro "B" es el destino de los datos de la hoja AVEVACons y la macro esta diseñada para trabajar en el libro "B".

Answer (score 0):

Según entiendo, la macro está creada en el libro donde tienes la hoja original "AVEVAcons", intenta con:

```
Thisworkbook.Sheets("AVEVACons").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
```

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte, William y bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor toma el [recorrido del sitio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour). Puedes consultar aquí [qué funciones tiene el sitio para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tus preguntas y/o respuestas](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78). Saludos.